# CSS Minify and Background-image syntax

Tags: css, minify

I have been looking for a reliable css minifier that doesn't require command line to run. Something similar to Google [closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) where you can input multiple JavaScript files and minify them into a single file. So far I have found [this](http://www.shrinker.ch/) from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232021/online-css-minifier-that-uses-the-yui-compressor).

I fed it a few css files and found that one of the images referenced in one of the css files was mangled in the minified file.

```
background-image: url('/abc/img.png')
```

and it was converted to

```
background-image: url(http://mydomain.com/'abc/img.png')
```

which doesn't look right. Oddly enough if only a single file with above code is fed the outcome is correct. Also, if I change background-image to background, again the outcome is correct. So I am a little confused as what the problem is:

*1* - Is it legal CSS to omit background-position when background-image is used?

*2* - Are there any alternatives to this tool (accept multiple css files to minify and doesn't require to be run as command).

Any other suggestions and insight is much appreciated.

Comment: This really should be 2 separate questions since they have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @cimmanon you are absolutely right that they are 2 separate questions, but they are related - however loosely. I wouldn't have part 2 if the tools is doing the right thing and I have bad css syntax, but if the css is valid then that is the context for asking for an alternative to the mentioned minifier tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `background` shorthand can be safely used with only the color or only the image portion.  I've been doing it this way since 2000~ because I'm lazy and never seen a problem.  Of course, you could have tried asking the CSS validator to see if it was valid or not (see: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).
2. Personally, I let Sass take care of my minification needs since I'm already using it for its other features.  I haven't paid too much attention to how well it crushes the generated file, but all whitespace and comments are removed in its most compact mode and colors are compressed to their 6 or 3 digit hex values.

Comment: why didn't I think of css validation :-)  I've been validating html, but not css and I knew I should start sooner rather than later. Thanks for the tip, and yes, the css code validates so it must be the minification problem. I am going to find more about Sass and see if I can use it too. I use Dreamweaver mainly for depository so if you or anybody else has an insight into Sass/DW I would appreciate the input.

Comment: I am accepting this answer although it doesn't explicitly answers the questions, but it does point to 2 resources that are very helpful. Yes, the code passes CSS validation so it must be valid CSS and Sass/Compass do a great job and can work their magic running on your system rather than accessing third party tools online.